# Start OrientDB studio for plocal DB

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm able to start my orientDb (2.2.6) instance using a plocal connection and able to add vertices to the DB but I can't access the studio. When I go to http://localhost:2480, the page is blank. Isn't studio ready and available 'out of the box'?

orientdb-server-config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<orient-server>
  <network>
    <protocols>
        <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
        <protocol name="http" implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpDb"/>
    </protocols>
    <listeners>
        <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
        <listener protocol="http" port-range="2480-2485" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
            <commands>
                <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetStaticContent" pattern="GET|www GET|studio/ GET| GET|*.htm GET|*.html GET|*.xml GET|*.jpeg GET|*.jpg GET|*.png GET|*.gif GET|*.js GET|*.css GET|*.swf GET|*.ico GET|*.txt GET|*.otf GET|*.pjs GET|*.svg">
                    <parameters>
                        <entry value="Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache" name="http.cache:*.htm *.html"/>
                        <entry value="Cache-Control: max-age=120" name="http.cache:default"/>
                    </parameters>
                </command>
            </commands>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
  </network>
  <users>
    <user resources="*" password="root" name="root"/>
    <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
  </users>
  <properties>
    <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
    <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
    <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
  </properties>
</orient-server>
```

I get these warnings whenever I try to access localhost:2480 from Chrome:

```
2016-09-28 16:56:01:756 WARNI path variable points to 'src/site' but it doesn't exists [OServerCommandGetStaticContent]
2016-09-28 16:56:01:756 WARNI path variable points to 'src/site' but it isn't a directory [OServerCommandGetStaticContent]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try to download the latest version, the warnings are pointing that you are missing some folders/files...

Comment: I've put this task on hold at the moment to fix an urgent issue. I'll take a look when I get time.

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko: I get the same problem when i use 2.2.12

Comment: What is your OS? Do you have some antivirus/firewall active?

Comment: I was able to get it started. I copied and pasted studio-2.2.zip into my plugin directory. I had to add some very permissive permissions that open up some major security vulnerabilities though.